# Automatically changing font size as parent control changes size

Tags: c#, wpf

I have several TextBlocks in a 6x2 grid and need to resize the text in the text TextBlocks as the parent control resizes. I don't know how to do this and am quite new to WPF. I am a few chapters into a book on WPF!

I don't know how to go about this. Can anyone help?

Mark

Comment: You may put the TextBlocks into Viewboxes.

Comment: I already tried that. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

How about this - it has the view box in each grid cell and a textbox as it's content. It will resize the content as you resize the app

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="286" Width="440">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition ></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition ></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Text="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock Text="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0">    
            <TextBlock Text="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Text="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Text="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Text="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>


        <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Text="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Text="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Text="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Text="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Text="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Text="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately. The font size doesn't change.

Comment: That is strange. So the text didn't grow as you resized the Window? Can you post the code you tried that didn't work. I'll try to replicate